# Manter script rodando

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Queria saber se existe uma forma de manter um script php rodando internamente no servidor mesmo com o navegador desligado. Não me refiro a agendar tarefas e sim manter um processo assim que deslogar do meu sistema. Vi em uma mineradora de bitcoin que após se deslogar da conta o processo de mineração continuava a funcionar em minha conta, queria fazer isso porém com meus scripts em particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mesmo que quem inicie a tarefa seja um navegador que requisitou a sua página, ainda sim terá que agendar, o que pode ser feito por funções como:

- `exec`
- `system`
- `shell_exec`

Pois o PHP em web é requisitado via HTTP ⇢ processa a resposta ⇢ devolve a resposta como download ⇢ a execução do script morre

Ou seja o script não teria como ficar executando eternamente.

Para usar `exec` e afins talvez seja necessário permissões para usar o CRONTAB, as vezes só é permitido para ROOT, um exemplo para agendar:

```
$resposta = shell_exec('25 15 * * * /var/www/cronjob/meuscriptcontinuo.php > /var/www/cronjob/meuscriptcontinuo.log');

var_dump($resposta);
```

E para checar os que já estão agendados:

```
<?php
$resposta = shell_exec('crontab -l');
var_dump($resposta);
```

Answer (score 4):

Caso você tenha acesso ao servidor SSH, você poderá executar o código abaixo para deixar o processo em background (mesmo deslogando do servidor).

```
nohup php -f /path/to/script.php &
```